Xiaomi Redmibook 16 2024 mic is not working
Ubuntu 24.04 desktop, any kernel version (even 6.9).
Sound has dummy output from the box.
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0 currently works for sound, but internal microphone does not work.
3.5 headset works.
Windows works fine with internal mic, device info:
INTELAUDIO\CTLR_DEV_7E28&LINKTYPE_02&DEVTYPE_00&VEN_8086&DEV_AE20&SUBSYS_1D722309&REV_10EC\5&1ed5312d&0&0000
Thanks

Ubuntu 24.04 desktop, any kernel version. Does not matter.
